# How to add style to link in this drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I have this drop-down menu which I found on a site:

```
<style>
body {background: #E3CAA1;}
ul {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<div style="text-align: right;padding: 20px 50px 150px;">
<ul><li>Home</li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li>
    Portfolio
    <ul>
      <li>Web Design</li>
      <li>Web Development</li>
      <li>Illustrations</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

When I tried changing simple text to link the effects was not implemented so I added this lines is `css`

```
ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
  }
```

and

```
ul li:hover,ul li a:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Now its working almost fine but the hover effect of the link takes place only when i hover on link but I want it to  take place as soon as cursor enters the block i.e when the background of `<li>` changes.
Can you please help me out of this ?
Also I want the whole `<li>` block to act as the link i.e user is not bounded to click only on the text but anywhere inside the block please help .

Comment: Where the Html ? where the fiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<style>
body {background: #E3CAA1;}
ul {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<div style="text-align: right;padding: 20px 50px 150px;">
<ul><li>Home</li>
  <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
  <li>
    Portfolio
    <ul>
      <li>Web Design</li>
      <li>Web Development</li>
      <li>Illustrations</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Watch demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2aJnC/)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your CSS to :

```
ul li:hover < ul li a, ul li a:hover {
    background:#555;
    colof:#fff;
}
```

Also the starting CSS before you modified it works perfectly : http://jsfiddle.net/NseLz/

Comment: Is sends the style to the element after the <

Comment: Also I want the whole <li> block to act as the link i.e user is not bounded to click only on the text but anywhere inside the block please help .

Comment: Move you <a> tags from inside the <li> tags to the outside of it so it looks like this :

    `<a href="#"><li>About</li></a>`

Comment: The fiddel is not working the link is displayed as an link with no style.

Comment: If you visit it now you will see that the bottom two lines of CSS have styled the link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated JSFiddle from DrRoach's answer: http://jsfiddle.net/3aP3m/

You needed to put the anchor tags outside of the list tags to make the entire block clickable, and I modified the CSS a bit to change the colors the way you wanted them, namely:

```
ul > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
    ul ul > a {
text-decoration:none;
    color: #fff;
}
```